# Map of methods in Go

Tags: methods, go

I have several methods that I'm calling for some cases (like Add, Delete, etc..). However over time the number of cases is increasing and my switch-case is getting longer. So I thought I'd create a map of methods, like [Go map of functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6769020/go-map-of-functions); here the mapping of *functions* is trivial. However, is it possible to create a map of *methods* in Go?

When we have a method:

```
func (f *Foo) Add(a string, b int) { }
```

The syntax below create compile-time error:

```
actions := map[string]func(a, b){
        "add": f.Add(a,b),
}
```

Is it possible to create a map of methods in Go?

Comment: Do you want to store just the function or both the function and a specific receiver ?

Comment: Without a receiver a method is basically useless, thus I guess I need definitely the receiver. Otherwise how can I call f.add(a,b)?

Comment: Well, you could pass the receiver dynamically when using the map, as in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8103617/call-a-struct-and-its-method-by-name-in-go

Comment: map[string]func/method seems like a poor variant of an interface in some sources floating around the intertubes. Hope this is not the same case.

Comment: @dystroy thanks. I guess MethodByName is what I really want. I can wrap it around a function and call every method directly with a string. Than I don't need any map of methods anymore.

Comment: @FatihArslan If you want it to be fast, you'd better use it only for initialization. You have other faster answers below and it's possible an interface would solve your problem more elegantly.

Comment: Oh, why is the answers below more faster than the MethodByName way? Is using `reflect` slow?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes. Currently:

```
actions := map[string]func(a string, b int){
        "add": func(a string, b int) { f.Add(a, b) },
}
```

Later: see the go11func document guelfi mentioned.

Comment: Great! I really like this (creating a func which calls the method). Thank you very much. Btw, I'm calling this like: `actions["add](a, b)`  .

Comment: It should be `actions["add"](a, b)`

Answer (score 3):

There is currently no way to store both receiver and method in a single value (unless you store it in a struct). This is currently worked on and it may change with Go 1.1 (see http://golang.org/s/go11func).

You may, however, assign a method to a function value (without a receiver) and pass the receiver to the value later:

```
package main

import "fmt"

type Foo struct {
    n int
}

func (f *Foo) Bar(m int) int {
    return f.n + m
}

func main() {
    foo := &Foo{2}
    f := (*Foo).Bar
    fmt.Printf("%T\n", f)
    fmt.Println(f(foo, 42))
}
```

This value can be stored in a map like anything else.

Comment: This works BTW because `func (f *Foo) Bar(m int)` is the same as `func Bar(f *Foo, m int)`.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using Method Expressions:

https://golang.org/ref/spec#Method_expressions

However, this makes the function take the receiver as a first argument:

```
actions := map[string]func(Foo, string, int){
  "add": Foo.Add
}
```

Similarly, you can get a function with the signature `func(*Foo, string, int)` using `(*Foo).Add`

Answer (score 1):

I met with a similar question.

How can this be done today, 9 years later:

the thing is that the receiver must be passed to the method map as the first argument. Which is pretty unusual.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "log"
)

type mType struct {
    str string
}

func (m *mType) getStr(s string) {
    fmt.Println(s)
    fmt.Println(m.str)
}

var (
    testmap = make(map[string]func(m *mType, s string))
)

func main() {
    test := &mType{
        str: "Internal string",
    }
    testmap["GetSTR"] = (*mType).getStr
    method, ok := testmap["GetSTR"]
    if !ok {
        log.Fatal("something goes wrong")
    }
    method(test, "External string")
}
```

https://go.dev/play/p/yy3aR_kMzHP

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use pointer to type Foo as receiver, like in:

```golang
func (f *Foo) Add(a string, b int) { }
```

then you can map string to function of (*Foo, string, int), like this:

```golang
var operations = map[string]func(*Foo, string, int){
    "add": (*Foo).Add,
    "delete": (*Foo).Delete,
}
```

Then you would use it as:

```golang
var foo Foo = ...
var op string = GetOp() // "add", "delete", ...
operations[op](&foo, a, b)
```

where `GetOp()` returns an operation as string, for example from a user input.
`a` and `b` are your string and int arguments to methods.

This assumes that all methods have the same signatures. They can also have return value(s), again of the same type(s).

It is also possible to do this with `Foo` as receiver instead of `*Foo`. In that case we don't have to de-reference it in the map, and we pass `foo` instead of `&foo`.